# Is there a better way of calling one particular task from role Ansible?

Tags: ansible, roles

Trying to install some custom packages for which prereq is to stop some service and start them later part. So created a role with two tasks stop/start service.

```
[ansibleadm@node1 ~]$ cat mypackageConfig.yaml
```

```yaml
---
- name: custom package installation
  hosts: remote
  become: yes
  roles:
   - role: manageServices
     serviceStop:
         - osquery
   - role: editFile
     updateStatement:
       - fileName: "/etc/audisp/plugins.d/syslog.conf"
         searchWord: "active"
         replaceWord: "active = yes"
   - role: manageServices
     serviceStart
         - auditd
```

```
[ansibleadm@node1 ~]$ cat roles/manageServices/tasks/main.yml
```

```yaml
---
# tasks file for manageServices
- name: start service
  systemd:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    enabled: yes
    state: started
  loop: '{{ myStartService }}'

- name: stop service
  systemd:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: stopped
  loop: '{{ myStopService }}'
```

While executing the role it states "undefined" as one of the task isn't called.

```
[ansibleadm@node1 ~]$
```

```
----------------------While executing playbook------------

TASK [manageServices: start service] **************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.20.20.12]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'manageServices' is undefined"}
```

Are there any better way of calling particular tasks from role or we need to create different roles for start/stop services in this situation?

Comment: I don't really see how Ansible would say `'manageServices' is undefined` while your code is not using any variable called `manageServices`. Are you sure the code you are providing here is correct? I guess not, since there is at least a typo in `serviceStart` missing a colon. This said, starting and stopping services are commonly managed whith [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html) in Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

In a playbook you can specify pre and post tasks.

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks

Rather than writing a whole role just to stop or start a service, specify the stop stask in pre, and the start task in post.